# Change form action with jQuery on submit

Tags: jquery

I have a filter form where I want to change the action URL with jQuery.

```
<form id="filter_form" action="">
     <div style=" bottom: 0; z-index: 1; width: calc(100% - 20px);">
        <input id="filter_submit" type="submit" value="Suchen" data-theme="b" >
      </div>
</form>


$("#filter_submit").on("click", function(e){
   $("#filter_form").attr("action", "/test/").submit();
});
```

This unfortunatelly does not work. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

It works, you just have to cancel the original event. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6oqy5jLz/

```js
$('input').on('click', function(e) {
  $('form').attr('action', '/bar').submit();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `return false` is a jQuery shortcut for `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`. You could also call those functions if you need more control over the event, e.g. if you need to control event propagation.

Comment: Good answer :) You beat me to it

Comment: Thank you, it works on the simulator and on safari ios, but chrome ios does somehow add a hash to the url. E.g. /test/#/bar/. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @merlin I don't use Chrome iOS so I can't say for sure, but perhaps there's some browser-specific or page-specific behavior leading to this. One potential workaround is to set `action` to an absolute URL - let me know if that works.

Comment: @imsky This is strange, I implemented absolute URLs an outputing via alert. The URL looks good, but the submit is wrong. Works on all other devices but not on iOS chrome 72.0.x

Comment: I opened another question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205254/chrome-ios-with-bug-within-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is totally possible. And you are almost there.

I think you just have to prevent the form from submitting until you have changed the action.

Try this (not tested - but I think it should work):

```
$("#filter_submit").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#filter_form").attr("action", "/test/").submit();
});
```