# Chrome iOS bug within form submit - redirects to wrong URL

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, mod-rewrite

I am changing the action attribute of a form via jQuery. This works on all major browser and devices BUT not on chrome 72.0.3626.101 iOS.

```
<form id="filter_form" action="/previous-folder/">
    <select name="brand" id="filter_brand">
        <option value="example">Example</option>
        <option value="test">Test</option>
    </select>
    <input id="filter_submit" type="submit" value="Suchen">
</form>
```

jquery code:

```
<script>
    $("#filter_submit").on("click", function(e){
       $("#filter_form").attr("action", "/"+$("#filter_brand").val()+"/").submit();
       return false;
    });
</script>
```

So the select button determines the URL and should go to /example/?para..

Instead it goes to `/previous-folder/#/example/?para`

The changing URL is correct, I tried outputing to console and it is OK. However the submited URL on iOS is the one mentioned. Works on all other devices.

The URL is by the way affected by an apache rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule  ^/home/www/(example/(.*))/(ref-.*)?$ /subapp_search/index.php?fa=1&rw=1 [L]
```

How to debug and fix such a behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to have any script in a submit button click event. Use the form submit event instead

```js
$("#filter_form").on("submit", function(e) {
  this.action =  "/" + $("#filter_brand").val() + "/"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="filter_form" action="/previous-folder/">
  <select name="brand" id="filter_brand">
    <option value="example">Example</option>
    <option value="test">Test</option>
  </select>
  <input id="filter_submit" type="submit" value="Suchen">
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I implemented it, but the same effect. Try it out: http://staging.www.de.watchgurus.de/rolex/ andy:newpw2 Click on "open", change brand to e.g. Omega and submit. Will go to /rolex/#/omega/?

Comment: But returns omega watches. I have a suspicion- I’ll take a look

Comment: Hmm, OK URL in Chrome when testing iPhone on a normal computer. Very strange.

Comment: Yes it returns the omega watches, but if you open again and select another brand, then it will fail as the URL is then totaly mixed up.

Comment: Seems to me to be a rewrite rule on the server or some mobile plugin, except then I would expect it to happen when I debugged in normal chrome as an iphone 6

Comment: Try changing the user agent in chrome and run again. It seems not to do what it is supposed to

Comment: Hmm...Interesting thought. There are rewrite rules, but they seem to work, also it does what it is supposed to, what do you mean?